# Call bean method from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a javascript code that needs to a string value from bean, for that i made a method in my bean that returns a string and i want have this string in my javascript wich is in JSF page, for this i have do this but doesn't work:

```
var valvar =eval("#{myBean.getChaine()}");
```

and it gives me this error:

> Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.

Translation: "The content of elements must include a markup or characters in the correct format"

How can give the javascript the value that  this method returns? I'm using JSF.

Comment: Please translate the french error message into english.

Comment: is EL enabled? Try ${myBean.chaine} instead of #{myBean.getChaine()}

Comment: sorry it doesn't work with $

Comment: following is working for me :
var valvar = "#{myBean.getChaine}";

Comment: i just put #{myBean.getChaine()} to see if the string watches a value or not and it show the value of JSF Bean, when i call it from javascript like this var valvar = "#{myBean.getChaine()}"; it result an error

Answer (score 0):

The eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. So, the correct code will be:

```
var valvar;
eval("valvar = myBean.getChaine()");
```

It's a bad practice to use the `eval` function because it's very slow.

Comment: PS: i call this method in XHTML file and i use JSF

Comment: Can you please open `Console` tab in the firebug (for FF) or Developer Tools (for Chrome) and run this code 
    myBean.getChaine()
. What will be your output ?

Comment: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /Map.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 43] Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.